# SOAP SSL connection in C# with certificate chain (CA Bundle)

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, soap

I'm having difficulties trying to connect to a 3rd-party SOAP server that requires two-way SSL. On the client side I have our certificate and private key, and I also have the self-signed certificate chain provided by the service provider. What I'm essentially trying to do is the C# equivalent of this Python code:

```
r = requests.post(
    url,
    verify=(ca_path),
    cert=(client_public_path, client_private_path),
    headers=headers,
    data=body)
```

Back in C# land, I've subscribed to the service and made it as far as this:

```
var endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://server.endpoint.com/");
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
using (var service = new MyServiceReference.ServerClient(binding, endpoint))
{
    X509Certificate certificate = LoadCertificate(client_public_path, client_private_path);
    service.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate = certificate;

    // how to set server CA Bundle?

    var response = service.SomeMethod(new Request{...});
```

At a bit of a loss though trying to figure out how to set the server-side chain? I have the two certs that are in the chain file, and I can also separate them out and load them into a X509Certificate2Collection if need be, just can't seem to figure out what to do with it after that?

The only other thing I've tried is assigning a custom validator on the server certificate:

```
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.Custom;
service.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CustomCertificateValidator = new MyValidator();
```

The custom validator's `Validate` method never gets called thoough, which if I'm not mistaken would suggest it's a either a problem with the client cert or the binding config?

Comment: You can refer to this link for how to create a custom certificate validator in WCF:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-create-a-service-that-employs-a-custom-certificate-validator?redirectedfrom=MSDN